# artifactory - can't set package type

Tags: npm, artifactory

I'm using artifactory to create a local npm repository cache system, but when I click on remote repositories then new, it is not letting me set npm as a package type. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Npm repositories is a feature of Artifactory Pro and Artifactory Online.